# Improving simple order query

Tags: php, mysql

I made mysql query like this:

```
SELECT m_id, user, date, home, away, pick, stake , odd, analiza, rezultat, sport, datetime 
FROM matches 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY $order DESC $limit
```

You can notice it is order by $order

At top of page I am searching for $order like this

```
if(isset($_GET['order'])){
  $order = $_GET['order'];
}
else{
  $order = "date";
}
```

How I can make that if user input in url lets say : index.php?order=date22 that $order  change to date. Because only two possible options are order by date and order by datetime.

Thanks

Comment: why would it be `index.php?order=date22` rather than `index.php?order=date`? Shouldn't it be either `?order=date` or `?order=datetime`?

Comment: in your query it seems you are getting order by field and limit from user input..if it is the case then you have to prepare first statement to execute your query with variable values and then you can execute that prepared statement...

Comment: Slightly off topic but switch to PDO. Or some other prepared statement  featured query api. Never trust a users input. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use switch/case.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b59f1344d928e56e551f11094a02e2e878799d06).

```
switch($_GET['order']){
case 'datetime':
$order = 'datetime';
break;
default:
$order = "date"; 
}
```

Comment: This will solve his Code Injection Problem for `$order` but does not at all provide an answer to his question now does it?

Comment: i made it like this :    $order = 'date'; 
if(!isset($_GET['order'])){}else{
switch($_GET['order']){
case 'datetime':
$order = 'datetime';
break;
default:
$order = "date"; 
}}
Thanks for help.